# Extract column from CSV and check columns length BASH

Tags: bash, csv, awk, cygwin

I have a multiple csv files  (68 files )
Rows are like

```
2#21231#132#1231132#26#123#0#1#81#44123#A#1236#123#
```

I want to check if length of column 11 for each row, for each file is equal to 208. And i want to count how many rows with length of column 11 equal to 208 ( count = count + 1)

I tried the script bellow but I get count is always 0

```
#!/bin/bash
date
ext='.UTF'
c=0
LIMIT=208
FILES=//DOC/*
for f in $FILES
do filename=$(echo $f| cut -d'/' -f 10)
   awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="#"}
   {  for(i=11;i<12;i++){
         if (length($i) -eq LIMIT);
         then let "c += 1";
         print ''length($i);
         fi
        }
   }  $i 1' $f
done
echo 'count == c'$c
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I cannot understand what do you want to do... perhaps you can reword your question and example?

Comment: Thanks for your reply,
I have 68 files, each file containt rows ( csv) like 2#203#8#2#26#70#0#1#81#441#Kleinchirurgischer urologischer Eingriff I#26#3#
I want to count all rows that their 11 column length is equal to 208 (example for this row: column number 11 contain : Kleinchirurgischer urologischer Eingriff I --> not equal to 208 so continue, if equal to 208 count = count +1 )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want something like this?

```
awk -F'#' '{c+=(length($11)==208?1:0)}END{printf "count=%d\n",c}' *.csv
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk -F'#' 'length($11)==208 {c++} END { print c+0 }' *.csv
```

Comment: Nice touch. Thanks.